# Keep Prompting Input From User

Tags: java, input, user-input

I have an assignment to do. I need to convert alphabets to telephone numbers. Add hyphen after the 3rd number and after every subsequent 4 numbers. Then I need to allow user to keep on entering input. 
I've already gotten 3/4 of my codes done. It's not working. I'm only stuck with the part to keep prompting user for input. 
This is my java code so far. Please help me and tell me what's wrong with my code. I'm new to Java, please be nice. Thank you!

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter letters: ");
    String phonenumber = input.next();
    String phone = phonenumber.replaceAll("\\s", " ");

    int count = 0; 
    int prevCount = 0;

    while (!phone.equals("#")){
    for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++)
        {
            char letter = Character.toLowerCase(phone.charAt(i));
            if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'b' || letter == 'c')
            {    
                System.out.print(2);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 'd' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'f')
            {
                System.out.print(3);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 'g' || letter == 'h' || letter == 'i')
            {
                System.out.print(4);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 'j' || letter == 'k' || letter == 'l')
            {
                System.out.print(5);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 'm' || letter == 'n' || letter == 'o')
            {
                System.out.print(6);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 'p' || letter == 'q' || letter == 'r' || letter == 's')
            {
                System.out.print(7);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 't' || letter == 'u' || letter == 'v')
            {
                System.out.print(8);
                count++;
            }

            if (letter == 'w' || letter == 'x' || letter == 'y' || letter == 'z')
            {
                System.out.print(9);
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 3 || count - prevCount == 4)
            {
                System.out.print('-');
                prevCount = count;
            } 
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter letters: ");
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a loop:

```
while (true)
{
 System.out.println("Enter letters: ");
 String phonenumber = input.next();

if something break;
```

or

```
while ((String phonenumber = input.next())!=null)
{ 
// ...
  System.out.println("Enter letters: ");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here :

```
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter letters: ");
    input.nextLine(); // you forgot to assign the String returned by nextLine
                      // into your phone variable
```

Beside that, you should reset your counters in each iteration of the while loop.

```
while (!phone.equals("#")) {
    int count = 0; 
    int prevCount = 0;
    ... your for loop ...
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter letters: ");
    phone = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank youu! I've finally got it.